# Adding keyboard short-cuts to toolbar buttons in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, keyboard-shortcuts, webbrowser-control, toolbar, browser-addons

Hii.. I have made a custom toolbar in IE. I would like to have keyboard shortcuts for the buttons of the same. Is it possible. Specifically I would like the toolbar options to be accessed by combination of keys like Ctrl+alt+A etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution using global keyboard hooks viz
 m_hhook = ::SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, KeyboardProc, NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());

For more details visit the link
http://www.ookii.org/post/ie_addon_development_globally_capturing_keyboard_input.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the right interface.  I'm not 100% sure off-hand what that is.  It could be [IInputObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761804%28VS.85%29.aspx).  It could be one of the crazy [OLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693372%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) interfaces.  You could set a breakpoint on your QueryInterface() implementation and see what it asks for.

Comment: The IInputObject works when we want to take user inputs in textboxes or the like, where our toolbar may get keyboard focus, which isn't the case here.